# How can mod_perl and Passenger run on the same Apache server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, mod-perl

Is this even possible?

I have a Rails app running on Passenger and a mod_perl site that need to run on the same server.  I've tried setting up two VirtualHosts and I've tried just using one VH and an Alias/Location for the mod_perl.  In both cases, Passenger tries to serve the mod_perl app and tells me it can't find the correct files.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my setup atm:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
RailsAutoDetect off
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot (home of rails app)/public
   RailsBaseURI /
</VirtualHost>

 PerlModule Apache::DBI
 PerlRequire /opt/rt3/bin/webmux.pl


Alias /rt /opt/rt3/share/html <== mod_perl app
<Location /rt>
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
  SetHandler perl-script
  PerlHandler RT::Mason
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for right now I've just set them up as two different VirtualHosts using different ports to connect.  That works, but it's a little messy for my site to use and if anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears.  Thanks.

Edit:  Got it working!  I ended up setting up two VirtualServers on different ports, then used mod-proxy to redirect traffic to the /rt site to the mod-perl VirtualServer (leaving the Passenger one as the default).  This works great, and best of all my mod_perl site believes it's still in the same place as Passenger, which smooths out a lot of compatibility issues I was dealing with as well.  I knew I was missing something simple!  Just putting this up in case anyone else is having issues with this.